# Converting multiple CSV files under similar directory to XLSX files

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv

I am converting multiple `CSV` files under the similar directory to `XLSX` files.

The `CSV` has delimiter as tab.

I executed the program and managed to generate the `XLSX` files. However, the `XLSX` files are not separate by the tab.

Please view my code and tell me what is wrong. In line 10, I have specified my delimiter as tab, but the resulting `XLSX` file is not separated.

```
import os
import glob
import csv
import openpyxl 

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join(r'(my directory)', '*.csv')):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        for r, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
            for c, val in enumerate(row, start=1):
                ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = val
    wb.save(csvfile + '.xlsx')
```

Comment: Is the alignment wrong, or are you opening the workbook each time in the loop and just saving it once outside?

Comment: yes,  it is supposed to open the workbook each time and saving it once in the similar diretory

Comment: Try this: `with open(csvfile) as f:
 reader = csv.reader(f)
 for r, row in enumerate(reader):
  for c, col in enumerate(row):
   for idx, val in enumerate(col.split('\t')):
    cell = sheet.cell(row=r+1, column=idx+1)
    cell.value = val`